# Find covariance matrix at time t

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, covariance, monte-carlo

A random state vector, $\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)$, evolves over time according to the following equation:
\begin{equation}
   \dot{\mathbf{x}}\left(t\right) = \mathbf{f}\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)\right)
\end{equation}
The state vector was initialized with a value of $\mathbf{x}\left(t_0\right)$ at time $t = 0$. However, this initial value is not known. The state vector was, first, observed at time $t = t_1$ and its value was measured as $\boldsymbol\mu\left(t_1\right)$. Let us ignore the measurement sensors noise characteristics. And assume that the only uncertainty in $\mathbf{x}\left(t_1\right)$ at time $t_1$ is due to its uncertainty at time $t=0$.

I want to get an estimate of the uncertainty(i.e. covariance matrix) at time $t_1$. Since we do not have any information about the values of $x\left(t\right)$ for $t < t_1$, we need to compute the covariance at $t = t_1$ by using information at time $t_1$ and beyond.

Let us assume that the evolution of the state vector is measured in a fixed frame called, world frame or w-frame. Here is how I am trying to estimate the uncertainty at time $t = t_1$:

1. Initialize the covariance, $\boldsymbol\Sigma\left(t_1\right)$ at time $t = t_1$ aligned with w-frame.
2. Create N samples of Monte Carlo (MC) points with mean $\boldsymbol\mu\left(t_1\right)$ and covariance $\boldsymbol\Sigma\left(t_1\right)$.
3. Propagate these MC points from time $t_1$ to $t_1+\Delta t_1$ where $\Delta t_1 \rightarrow 0$.
4. Compute the covariance, $\hat{\boldsymbol\Sigma}$, of MC points at time $t_1+\Delta t_1$.
5. $\hat{\boldsymbol\Sigma}$ is, then, a good approximation of uncertainty in state vector $\mathbf{x}\left(t_1\right)$.

Is this the correct way to compute covariance at time $t_1$? Is there any better way to do it?